# How to start learning salesforce with a sample project

Tags: administration, configuration, help

I am new to crm , so i don't know how logically use salesforce for developerment.

I read some tutorial, learned visual force and experiment some task mention in the tutorial.

But there is lack of implementation.

I need a tutorial with some industry implementation.For example consider e-commerce company planning to use salesforce.

Can you suggest a good tutorial with sample project.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/SravanAlaparthi/videos

Comment: Somebody recently asked similar thing on our chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15586499#15586499 (can you access this link or do you need 20 reputation to see it?)

Comment: thank you really very good suggestions , thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best free resource that I know of is the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) which will take you through the process of building a recruiting application for a fictional company called Universal Containers.

The Fundamentals mainly covers declarative (point-and-click) development, but everything it covers will be fundamental (no pun intended) to any serious application you develop using SFDC.

Here are some other resources provided by SFDC that you might find helpful:

- [Visualforce Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_intro.htm)
- [Salesforce YouTube Channell - Salesforce How-To's](https://www.youtube.com/user/salesforce/playlists?sort=dd&shelf_id=15&view=50)
- [Apex Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_intro.htm)

Comment: Thank you , i am really looking this kind of example.I just opened and go through it quickly.Learning something with some real time industry example is good.

Answer (score 1):

This is very open ended question but let me try answering it as per my understanding.

You should follow this steps:

1) Search for various workbooks that SFDC provides for beginners
2) Search for 401 training videos those are very good  http://www.salesforcetrainingpodcasts.com/podcasts/401/
3) Go through apex & VF developer guide
4) There are many free apps install and try them in your dev org
5) Try and create your own app

Dont expect that that some will give you industry implementation project just to learn SFDC.

Comment: hi, nice suggestion.But i am not looking for my industry implementation help.Consider i am php developer.If you learn forms in php.the tutorial will be like teach a how to create a contact form.Now you learned php forms along with real time knowledge.This what i am looking for.

Comment: Good. In that case above list will help you.